# langchain custom prompts & input parameters not clear

Tags: langchain

I do not understand how customprompt works in the example documentation: https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/qa_with_sources.html

prompt object is defined as:

`PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["summaries", "question"])`

expecting two inputs summaries and question

However, what is passed in **only question (as query)** and **NOT summaries**

```
chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="stuff", prompt=PROMPT)
query = "What did the president say about Justice Breyer"
chain({"input_documents": docs, "question": query}, return_only_outputs=True)
where docs = docsearch.similarity_search(query)
```

Question 1 (for `qa_with_sources`):
How did ***input_documents*** map to summaries?

Similarly, I am not clear about the documentation at link
https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/summarize.html

```
prompt_template = """Write a concise summary of the following:


{text}


CONCISE SUMMARY IN ITALIAN:"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["text"])
chain = load_summarize_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="map_reduce", return_intermediate_steps=True, map_prompt=PROMPT, combine_prompt=PROMPT)
chain({"input_documents": docs}, return_only_outputs=True)
```

More questions (for `summarize`):
2. how did ***docs*** map to ***text***, where can I know about this?
3. how does it work with map_prompt and combine_prompt being same?
4. where can i see the parameters of function? when i use code `print('load_summarize_chain params: ', inspect.signature(load_summarize_chain))`, I simply get the following output

> load_summarize_chain params:  (llm:
> langchain.schema.BaseLanguageModel, chain_type: str = 'stuff',
> verbose: Optional[bool] = None, **kwargs: Any) ->
> langchain.chains.combine_documents.base.BaseCombineDocumentsChain

Answer (score 17):

Still learning LangChain here myself, but I will share the answers I've come up with in my own search.

Notes:

- OP questions edited lightly for clarity.
- Each of these questions is probably better as its own separate post, but I did appreciate having them all together as it pushed me to connect the dots between them. So here's hoping this is useful to others as well.

### Question 1

In [`load_qa_with_sources_chain()`](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/qa_with_sources.html#the-stuff-chain), `PROMPT` is defined as:

> `PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["summaries", "question"])`

which expects two inputs, `'summaries'` and `'question'`.

However, what is passed in only `question=query` and NOT `'summaries'`.

> `chain = load_qa_with_sources_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="stuff", prompt=PROMPT) query = "What did the president say about Justice Breyer" chain({"input_documents": docs, "question": query}, return_only_outputs=True)`

How does `input_documents` map to `summaries`?

### Answer 1

First, the [`stuff` chain loader](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/3bd5a99b835fa320d02aa733cb0c0bc4a87724fa/langchain/chains/qa_with_sources/loading.py#LL48C1-L63C6) takes the prompt we pass in and defines an `LLMChain` with that prompt. And then you can see that that `llm_chain` is used to initialize a `StuffDocumentsChain`.

```
def _load_stuff_chain(
    llm: BaseLanguageModel,
    prompt: BasePromptTemplate = stuff_prompt.PROMPT,
    document_prompt: BasePromptTemplate = stuff_prompt.EXAMPLE_PROMPT,
    document_variable_name: str = "summaries",
    verbose: Optional[bool] = None,
    **kwargs: Any,
) -> StuffDocumentsChain:
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt, verbose=verbose)
    return StuffDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=llm_chain,
        document_variable_name=document_variable_name,
        document_prompt=document_prompt,
        verbose=verbose,
        **kwargs,
    )
```

But also notice that there are two other arguments to `_load_stuff_chain()`:  `document_prompt` and `document_variable_name`.

- `document_prompt`: If we do not pass in a custom `document_prompt`, it relies on the [`EXAMPLE_PROMPT`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/master/langchain/chains/qa_with_sources/stuff_prompt.py), which is quite specific. (It is long so I won't repost here.).
- `document_variable_name`: Here you can see where `'summaries'` first appears as a default value. And we can see it [defined](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/combine_documents/stuff.py#L32) as

> the variable name in the llm_chain to put the documents in

In that same `stuff.py` script there is a `_get_inputs()` method that collects all of the inputs that will go into the LLM for evaluation. One of those inputs is

> `inputs[self.document_variable_name] = self.document_separator.join(doc_strings)`

So now we know this is actually `inputs['summaries']` by default. Also, side note, `doc_strings` is each `doc` in `docs` formatted using `document_prompt` (via [`format_document()`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/combine_documents/base.py#L18)).

Ok, so now we are almost there, the final step in the `stuff` system is to send all of the `docs`, formatted into `document_prompts`, to the `llm_chain` for evaluation. That is done in `combine_docs()` - ending in this call to [`llm_chain.predict()`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/combine_documents/stuff.py#L87):

> `return self.llm_chain.predict(callbacks=callbacks, **inputs), {}`

Remember, we initialized `llm_chain` with the original `PROMPT` we passed in, and now it is clear that it is both expecting `'question'` AND `'summaries'` as input variables.

### Question 2

In the [`summarize_chain` example](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/summarize.html#the-map-reduce-chain):

```
prompt_template = """Write a concise summary of the following:


{text}


CONCISE SUMMARY IN ITALIAN:"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["text"])
chain = load_summarize_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="map_reduce", return_intermediate_steps=True, map_prompt=PROMPT, combine_prompt=PROMPT)
chain({"input_documents": docs}, return_only_outputs=True)
```

How does `docs` map to `text`?

### Answer 2

This gets easier from here, as a lot of the `summarize` chain code follows similar patterns to the `qa` chain.

We can see in [`_load_map_reduce_chain()`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/summarize/__init__.py#L40) there's [a default value](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/summarize/__init__.py#L45), `'text'`, which gets assigned to [`document_variable_name`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/summarize/__init__.py#L81) in the `MapReduceDocumentChain` that is initialized and returned.

Also note L52 and L54 where two different `LLMChain` objects are initialized, one for `map` (takes `map_prompt`) and one for `reduce` (takes `combine_prompt`).

```
# L52
map_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=map_prompt, verbose=verbose)
# L54
reduce_chain = LLMChain(llm=_reduce_llm, prompt=combine_prompt, verbose=verbose)
```

And then `reduce_chain` is built into `combine_document_chain`, which is where we can first see the relationship coming in between `'text'` (the default value for `combine_document_variable_name`) and `PROMPT` (now built into `reduce_chain`).

```
 combine_document_chain = StuffDocumentsChain(
        llm_chain=reduce_chain,
        document_variable_name=combine_document_variable_name,
        verbose=verbose,
    )
```

### Question 3

How does it work with `map_prompt` and `combine_prompt` being same?

### Answer 3

The fact that both prompts are the same here looks like it may be for the convenience of the example, as the suggested prompt is generic:
>`"Write a concise summary of the following: {text} #..."`

The user can enter different values for `map_prompt` and `combine_prompt`; the map step applies a prompt to each document, and the combine step applies one prompt to bring the map results together.

You can see where these steps occur in the code:

The LLM chain for `map` is applied in [`combine_docs()`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/c26cf04110b799a9cf7ac088e9ece67ef1e43bb5/langchain/chains/combine_documents/map_reduce.py#L144) step of the `MapReduceDocumentsChain`:

```
# self.document_variable_name = 'text'
# d.page_content is the text content from each :doc: in :docs:

"""Combine documents in a map reduce manner.

Combine by mapping first chain over all documents, then reducing the results.
This reducing can be done recursively if needed (if there are many documents).
"""
# L144
results = self.llm_chain.apply(
            # FYI - this is parallelized and so it is fast.
            [{self.document_variable_name: d.page_content, **kwargs} for d in docs],
            callbacks=callbacks,
        )
```

And then the reduce steps are called in the [`_process_results()` method](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/c26cf04110b799a9cf7ac088e9ece67ef1e43bb5/langchain/chains/combine_documents/map_reduce.py#L168), specifically in the `_collapse_chain()` and `combine_documents_chain()` sections.

### Question 4

Where can i see the parameters of the `load_summarize_chain()` function?

### Answer 4

All of the `summarize` variants (`stuff`, `map_reduce`, etc) are defined in [`summarize/__init__.py`](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/blob/71a337dac6aa8c5a7f472e3e7fd0a61ca2a4eefb/langchain/chains/summarize/__init__.py#L40).  In this particular example, the `map_reduce` chain parameters are on L40-51.