# ChatBot langchain, set memory+retriever+map_reduce

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, openai-api, langchain

I am new on this topics.I'd like to get a chain that allows me to use a retriever ,a memory and to set the chain_type = 'map_reduce'.In addition to that I'd like to know if is it possible to use the map_reduce only in the case in which the number of token exceeds the limit.Thanks in advice.

I tried to use the 'ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm' or 'RetrievalQA.from_llm' but I'm not figuring out how to combine the different functions of the chains.

Answer (score 0):

> it possible to use the map_reduce only in the case in which the
> number of token exceeds the limit.

that is the purpose of `map_reduce`. It will first summarize the documents, and then combine them and then make a summarization of those combined summaries. your final output will fit within the token limit of the model

Here is your code

```
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA

qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
    llm=ChatOpenAI(),
    chain_type='map_reduce',
    retriever=retriever,
    chain_type_kwargs={    
        "prompt": SETYOURPROMPTHERE,
        "memory": SETYOURMEMORYHERE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pasting an answer that I found on Github as is, cause there could be some more details added to the other answer:

### Map_reduce

- **Map_reduce**: This chain type applies a map function to each retrieved document and then combines them using a reduce function. The expected input variable for the map prompt template is **text**, which is the text content of each document. The expected input variable for the combine prompt template is **texts**, which is a list of texts returned by the map function. For example, if your map prompt template is:

```py
map_template = "Write a summary of the following text:\n\n{text}"
map_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=map_template, input_variables=["text"])
```

And your combine prompt template is:

```py
combine_template = "Write an answer to the following question based on these summaries:\n\n{question}\n\n{texts}"
combine_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=combine_template, input_variables=["question", "texts"])
```

Then you should pass them as arguments to the **load_qa_chain** function or the **from_chain_type** method. For example:

```py
qa_chain = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(), chain_type="map_reduce", map_prompt=map_prompt_template, combine_prompt=combine_prompt_template)
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="map_reduce", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), chain_type_kwargs={"map_prompt": map_prompt_template, "combine_prompt": combine_prompt_template})
```

#### testing 1

Sure, I can create a custom map reduce prompt template for you. Here is an example of how to do it:

```py
# Create a custom map prompt template that asks the language model to extract the main idea of each document
map_template = "Write the main idea of the following document in one sentence:\n\n{text}"
map_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=map_template, input_variables=["text"])

# Create a custom combine prompt template that asks the language model to use the main ideas to answer the question
combine_template = "Use the main ideas of the retrieved documents to answer the question: {question}\n\n{texts}"
combine_prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=combine_template, input_variables=["question", "texts"])

# Pass the custom prompt templates to the load_qa_chain function or the from_chain_type method
qa_chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="map_reduce", map_prompt=map_prompt_template, combine_prompt=combine_prompt_template)
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="map_reduce", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), chain_type_kwargs={"map_prompt": map_prompt_template, "combine_prompt": combine_prompt_template})
```

This will create a retrievalqa chain that uses the map_reduce chain type, which applies the custom map prompt template to each retrieved document and then combines them using the custom combine prompt template. I hope this helps you create and use a custom map reduce prompt template.

#### testing 2

It seems that you are getting a validation error for the **StuffDocumentsChain**. This might be because you are not passing the **document_variable_name** argument to the **load_qa_chain** function or the **from_chain_type** method. According to the Langchain documentation¹, the **document_variable_name** argument is the name of the variable in the llm_chain to put the documents in. For example, if your prompt template is:

```py
template = "Answer the following question based on the retrieved documents: {question}\n\n{summaries}"
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["question", "summaries"])
```

Then you should pass **document_variable_name="summaries"** as an argument to the **load_qa_chain** function or the **from_chain_type** method. For example:

```py
qa_chain = load_qa_chain(llm=llm, chain_type="map_reduce", map_prompt=map_prompt_template, combine_prompt=combine_prompt_template, document_variable_name="summaries")
qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=OpenAI(), chain_type="map_reduce", retriever=docsearch.as_retriever(), chain_type_kwargs={"map_prompt": map_prompt_template, "combine_prompt": combine_prompt_template, "document_variable_name": "summaries"})
```

I found a similar question on Stack Overflow² that might be helpful. I hope this solves your problem.

Quelle: Unterhaltung mit Bing, 3.8.2023
(1) langchain custom prompts & input parameters not clear. [langchain custom prompts & input parameters not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76093852/langchain-custom-prompts-input-parameters-not-clear).
(2) How to use StuffDocumentsChain / Error when using third input variable .... https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/504.
(3) StuffDocumentsChain | ️ Langchain. https://js.langchain.com/docs/api/chains/classes/StuffDocumentsChain.